# Prevent list elements from moving when javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an Unordered List with three list items placed side by side on a page, each of them having a button that can be clicked - then a message will appear. I have almost finished this setup, but I am facing a problem related to the button displaying the message.

When the button is pressed the whole list item is been moved out of line, this happens to all the three list items. (please test the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63mdnjxd/) to se this problem in action)

How can I prevent this from happening and have the list items not change their position when clicked?

CSS used:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.product {
    color: #5a5b5d;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;     
}

ul.products {
    text-align: center; 
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
}


.products li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px 10px;  
    padding: 45px 5px;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 400px; 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #427cb7;
    background-color: #c6d7e9;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.products ul li h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5a5b5d;
      font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;    
      text-transform: uppercase;  
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      font-size: 22px;  
      text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: The `<p>` starts with zero height. Depending on how much text you're going to stuff in it, you might want to set its height or just set its initial content to `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

If you just add overflow:hidden to .products li it should do the trick! Only catch is the box will be 400px tall and won't grow, so if your message is really long you'll need to increase the height of your boxes.

```
.products li {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px 10px;  
    padding: 45px 5px;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 400px; 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #427cb7;
    background-color: #c6d7e9;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your li CSS rules:

```
.products li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px 10px;  
    padding: 45px 5px;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 400px; 
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #427cb7;
    background-color: #c6d7e9;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5deoy0Lx/)**